# javascript or php, convert decimal latitude to degrees latitude

Tags: php, javascript, latitude-longitude

Does anyone know the function to convert decimal latitude to degrees latitude and also the reverse?

Comment: I've been using this library to do my conversions: [JScoord](http://www.jstott.me.uk/jscoord/)

Comment: Do you mean radians to degrees? Or do you mean decimal degrees to degrees, minutes, seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a basic math problem.  If you've got a decimal number, like "33.25", and you have to convert to a different representation like degrees and minutes, you just multiply the fractional part by the number of minutes in a degree.  In other words, "33.25" means "33 degrees and 0.25 * 60 minutes".  Once you get the number of minutes, you can repeat the process to get seconds.